# Controller name at error 500?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I get the controller_name, action_name at the moment of error 500?
I am trying to detect where the error occurs at my rails app

I send the error by email, but I need more details, any idea? what's the common way of doing this? is there a good gem for this? or what's the recommended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using gem https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake

or may be open https://github.com/errbit/errbit, host on heroku and enjoy for free.

Comment: It seems lots of things to learn here, isnt there more simple solution, just to get action name and controller name? what line?

Comment: airbrake will give you all details. Its simple to install and get started. Merely 15 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I found sentry which seems to have free account for testing..